# Django REST get nested data in request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm new usigng django and drf .
I have an issue with request a model with a foreig key.

I have this 3 models :

```py
    class Order(models.Model):
       id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
       fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

       def __str__(self):
           return f"Orden : {self.id}"

    class Product(models.Model):
       id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
       name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

       def __str__(self):
           return self.name

    class OrderDetail(models.Model):
       order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name="orders", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="products", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to retrieve all order data with its products from detail:

Example :

```
 
{ oders :[    
    { id : 1 ,
        user : 1 ,
        fecha : 01/02/2021,
        products : [ 
            { id : 1 , name : "product1" }
            { id : 2 , name : "prodcut2" }
     },
    { id : 2 ,
        user : 2 ,
        fecha : 10/02/2021,
        products : [ 
            { id : 3 , name : "product3" }
        ]
     }
    ]}
```

My serializers are :

```py
    class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = ["id", "name"]
    
    
    class OrderDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = OrderDetail
            fields = ['order' ,'product']
    
    
    class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        products = OrderDetailSerializer(many=True)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Order
            fields = ['id', 'user', 'fecha' ,'products']
```

But I'm getting this error :

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'products' on serializer 'OrderSerializer'.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the 'Order' instance.
Original exception text was: 'Order' object has no attribute 'products'.

I'm using :

```
Django==3.2.5
djangorestframework==3.12.4
python==3.8
```

I'll appreciate if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Add many to many relation through orderdetail model

```
class Order(models.Model):
       id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
       fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
       products = models.ManyToMany(Product, through="OrderDetail")

       def __str__(self):
           return f"Orden : {self.id}"
```